# What is the right way to use __declspec(dllexport) in this case

Tags: c++, dll

I have a math library which is not large. The authors heavily use Eigen library. The library is meant to be used in Linux (i.e. the authors claim the library is partially supported in Windows and I will tell you shortly why) and there is only one dll. CMakeLists.txt is available but when I use it in Windows 10, Visual Studio generates dll without its lib. I believe this is because the source codes are missing `__declspec(dllexport)`. Adding `__declspec(dllexport)` to each class is doable but because Eigen and STL libraries are used, there is a plethora of warnings; however, I've tried this solution but when I use the dll in another project, the code crashes. What is the right way to use `dllexport` so that the code should compile without warnings and generate the .lib? It would be great if this can be handled from CMakeLists.txt.

Comment: Did you try debugging the crash?  If you know enough to drill down to the assembler level then I would do so, as this might reveal what is causing it.  One possibility is a calling convention mismatch.  Another is passing C++ objects across the API (does the library do that?) which have different representations in the app and in the DLL.  Also, the app and the DLL need to be built against the same version of the C runtime (including Debug vs Release, and static vs dynamic), although I think you get a warning from the linker if you mix them up.  (more)

Comment: ... and if you are passing something which is `malloc`ed or `new`ed across the API boundary, then you need to free it /delete it in the same 'component' (app or DLL) that allocated it, unless you link against the dynamic C runtime (i.e. the DLL version, not the .lib version).  Ditto if you want to pass something like a `FILE *` or a `stream` across - it will only be valid on the side of the API that allocated it unless you do this.  As for the warnings, you should show us what they are!

Comment: CMake won't help you fix those warnings and probably you should listen to them anyway, since one possible reason for the crash is an incompatible abi... In general you create a header though containing a define that contains either `__declspec(dllexport)`, if a certain preprocessor symbol is defined, which cmake can do for you: `#ifdef _WIN32 #ifdef MYLIB_EXPORT_SYMBOLS #define MYLIB_IMEXPORT __declspec(dllexport) #else #define MYLIB_IMEXPORT __declspec(dllimport) #endif #else #define MYLIB_IMEXPORT #endif` `target_compile_definitions(MyLib PRIVATE MYLIB_EXPORT_SYMBOLS)`

Comment: @PaulSanders sorry I can't go to the level of  the assembler. The library works fine in Linux and I'm using the examples shipped with the library, so I guess the misusing `__declspec(dllexport)` causes the problems.

Comment: OK, but I did suggest a number of possible causes for the crash so you should investigate those, and running your app under the debugger to see if anything jumps out at you is never a bad thing to do.  At minimum, you will find out which call(s) are failing.  As for the code working on Linux, that's probably because Windows has a lot of issues interfacing applications to DLLs that Linux simply doesn't have.